# Excel VBA - Loop through range and add values to array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function which can accept an array like `{variant, variant, variant}` as a parameter. Right now, it can also accept a range of cells like `A1:A3` as the same parameter, but can't process the results.

I think what I need to do is loop through the range, and add each value to an array, for example:

- `A1:A3` becomes `{Value in A1, Value in A2, Value in A3}`
- `A1:B2` becomes `{A1, A2, B1, B2}`
- `A:A` becomes an array with only the populated cells of column A (the same principle can apply to the two ranges above. Only populated cells are added to the array)

That way, I can process the result the same way as if the user had typed out the array themselves when inputting the parameter.

How can I do this without knowing the size of the range beforehand? I'd like the user to be able to provide a range of any size/shape that I can convert into an array.

`IsArray()` returns true for both inputs of `{variant, variant, variant}` and `A1:A3`, so then I check if it's a range with `If TypeName(parameter) = "Range" Then`, but afterward I'm having trouble dealing with the range and don't know how to proceed converting it into an array.

I've tried researching but I'm new to VBA and I think I'm using incorrect terms in my searches. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Updated to include some code. Please note that this will be the very first thing the function will do. Later code isn't that relevant to the question except in that the later code requires an array of values to process.

```
If IsArray(my_values) Then

    'If it's a Range then I need to get the values of each cell and put them into an array.
    'If they passed an array like `{1,1,1}`, move on and process the array
    If TypeName(my_values) = "Range" Then
        Dim rows_count As Long
        Dim columns_count As Long
        Dim cells_count As Long

        'Just testing, not sure if necessary
        rows_count = my_values.rows.Count
        columns_count = my_values.columns.Count
        cells_count = rows_count * columns_count
        'Or just cells_count = my_values.Cells.Count

        'Need to loop through each cell in the range now and put the values into an array

    End If

    'Continue processing the array
```

Comment: A `Range` object has a `Rows` property which has a `Count` property (and the same for `Columns`) so you can just loop from `1 To rng.Rows.Count`.  It also has a `Cells` property so you could loop from `1 To rng.Cells.Count`.  Or you could do a `For Each anotherRange In rng.Cells`, etc.  There are a **lot** of ways to do this.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code**

Comment: the first line in my answer to your previous question converts the Range to array `If TypeOf my_values Is Range Then my_values = my_values`

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
Public Function RangeToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        arr(i) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
     Next r

    RangeToArray = arr
End Function
```

[image]

as an example.

When we array-enter the function in the worksheet, we must be sure to hi-light enough cells in the row *(8)* to accommodate the 8-cell input range.

This approach can be adapted to handle any size or shape input range.

Answer (score 2):

Given your argument being variant, and that you will always want the output of the function to be an array, and also that you will have a single input as the argument which can be a range, an array constant, or a non-array constant, the following function will always output an array (even if the input is a non-array constant)

```
Option Explicit
Function makeArray(myArray As Variant) As Variant
    Select Case IsArray(myArray)
        Case True
            makeArray = myArray
        Case False
            makeArray = Array(myArray)
    End Select
End Function
```

In the case of a range, the output will be a 2D array, with d1 representing the rows, and d2 representing the columns.

Otherwise the output will have the same dimensions as the input.
If the input is not an array, then the output will be an array with one dimension and one value.